# How do I enable my desired semantics on a natural numbers value class?

Tags: scala

For a project I am working on I want to create a class representing a count of resources. In future it might become a collection of counts of different resource types (hence not coding the Resources class itself as a Value class), but for now a single (anonymous) resource type is sufficient.

This resources count should never be negative, though, so I want to restrict the values that it can have to the set of natural numbers (ie. non-negative integers). For this I am looking at creating a new Value Class called Nat.

A couple of semantic points that I want to achieve:

- If you try to create a Nat from a negative value, you should get an exception thrown.
- If you try to add an Int (or another Nat) to an existing Nat, it should work, truncating the value to zero if the int passed in was a large enough negative number - no exception thrown!

This means that as well as `def +(nat: Nat)`, I also want some form of `def +(int: Int)`, otherwise an Int passed to `+` will be converted to a Nat first, which could cause an exception. Because Nat is a Value class, though, these two methods would have the same signature after erasure, so that won't work.

I also tried `def +(int: RichInt)`, hoping for the implicit conversion to take precedence, but RichInt is also a Value class so the same problem ensues.

One work around I did discover is to use one of the traits that is mixed in to RichInt, specifically, OrderedProxy. Now an Int will be implicitly converted to a RichInt and passed to this method as an OrderedProxy (in which form it is not recognised as a Value class) in preference to being converted into a Nat, and I get the semantics I want.

Thus, my code so far looks like the following:

```
import runtime.{IntegralProxy, OrderedProxy}

class Nat private(val self: Int) extends AnyVal with IntegralProxy[Int]
{
  protected def num = scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral
  protected def ord = scala.math.Ordering.Int

  import Nat._
  def isZero = (this == Zero)
  def +(nat: Nat): Nat = Nat(self + nat.self)
  def +(int: OrderedProxy[Int]): Nat = trunc(self + int.self)
  def -(nat: Nat): Nat = trunc(self - nat.self)
  def -(int: OrderedProxy[Int]): Nat = trunc(self - int.self)
  def -%(nat: Nat) = (this - nat).self match { // Create a tuple with the reduced count of the minuend, plus any remainder from the subtrahend if the minuend is now zero.
    case 0 => (Zero, (nat - this))
    case nonZero => (Nat(nonZero), Zero)
  }
}

object Nat
{
  val NEG_PARAM_MSG = "Cannot assign negative value"

  val Zero: Nat = Nat(0)

  def apply(value: Int): Nat = value match {
      case cnt if (cnt < 0) => throw new RuntimeException(NEG_PARAM_MSG)
      case 0 => Zero
      case cnt => new Nat(cnt)
    }

  def apply(value: Long): Nat = apply(value.toInt)

  def trunc(value: Int): Nat = value match {
      case cnt if (cnt <= 0) => Zero
      case cnt => new Nat(cnt)
    }

  def trunc(value: Long): Nat = trunc(value.toInt)
}

trait ResourcesComponent
{
  import Nat._

  sealed case class Resources(count: Nat)
  {
    import Resources._

    require(count != Zero || hasNone)

    def hasNone = (this == none)
    def +(res: Resources) = Resources(count + res.count)
    def -(res: Resources) = Resources(count - res.count)
    def -%(res: Resources) = (count - res.count).self match { // Similar to -% for Nat, but convert to a tuple of Resources - is there a better (eg. '.map'-like) way to do this?
      case 0 => (none, Resources(res.count - count))
      case leftOver => (Resources(leftOver), none)
    }
  }

  object Resources
  {
    val NEG_RES_MSG = "Cannot assign negative resources"

    def apply(value: OrderedProxy[Int]) = value.self match {
        case cnt if (cnt < 0) => throw new RuntimeException(NEG_RES_MSG)
        case 0 => none
        case cnt => new Resources(Nat(cnt))
      }

    object none extends Resources(Zero)
    {
      override def hasNone = true
      override def +(res: Resources) = res
      override def -(res: Resources) = none
      override def -%(res: Resources) = (none, res)
    }
  }
}
```

As I say, it seems to work, but the work around feels a bit kludgy. Any suggestions on improving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:  also truncate to zero when constructing `Nat`s from negative integers.  Apart from being simpler, the solution will be more consistent.  I don't see why `aNat + -1` would work differently than `aNat + Nat(-1)` (including the case of both throwing the same exception).  In fact, the programming language itself is telling you that this consistency problem exists, by forcing you into a complex, unnatural construct.

If you really want to make this difference between `Int`s and `Nat`s, then don't try to trick the language (and other developers!).  Be honest with it and define a completely different operator for `Int`s.  Not just an overload.  Suggested name:  `safeAdd`, `intAdd`,  or similar.

Comment: Hmm, I definitely want an exception thrown if you try to create an invalid Nat, so to follow your recommendation I would need to accept that an exception will be thrown when adding an Int to a Nat. Fair enough, I'll take some time to think that through.

I don't think the intAdd idea works, though, as you could still call `+` with an Int, and it will be auto-converted to a Nat (with possible exception thrown), and indeed you could call intAdd passing a Nat. Having a safeAdd (again, accepting both Int or Nat) might work.

Comment: Thinking it through further, probably what I really want is to disallow ever having `+` called with a negative number (even if it is a small negative number, so that the result would still be a valid Nat) - in which case I could ensure this by only having the `+(int: Int)` version (which will also accept Nats), and checking against negative values in the method.

Comment: Makes sense to me.  That forces handling of negatives into the client code, which probably has more contextual information than the generic Nat type.